# WiFi Drivers disabled on restart

Tags: wireless, macbook

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro with Broadcomm BCM4331 as wifi device.
Every time I restart Ubuntu, my Wifi drivers get automatically checked to "Do not use".
Can anyone help with that.